# Posting Edited Questions in Chat

Tags: bug, chat, onebox

I've recently noticed an issue in my [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap-consultancy-) where if I post a link to a question that has been edited that the one box feature no longer shows the question details and instead shows a standard link.

Here is a walk through of exactly how this happens.

First go to a question.

> [image: OriginalQ]

Then post the link in chat.

> [image: PostedLink]

As you can see everything works as expected.

Now if someone edits the link the standard prompt appears stating an edit has been made to this post.

> [image: Click Link]

Then the URL is changed at the top when the page is reloaded to have a `#` included in it.

> [image: HasLink]

Now if I post that link in chat it shows up as a plain link.

> [image: Boring]

If I refresh the page by click on the question title the # goes away and I can re-post as normal.

Is there an explanation or a fix that can be made for this?

EDIT: @AaronBertrand noticed the mouse over on that link behaves weird as well.

> [image: OriginalMouseOver]
>
> [image: MomentsLater]

Comment: This is definitely broken functinality in some way, and I'm not sure what changed, but it was recent - and has affected me multiple times today.

Comment: Yup, we reproduced this several times today.

Comment: I've always noticed this behavior. It seems that using `#` in the URL blows up the parser.